# Facebook Addthis like button when clicked pop up box part dissapears

Tags: css, facebook-like

I added the "addthis" Facebook like buttons to certain pages on my website.

Trouble is if someone clicks it, the add comment pop up box appears, but only half of it. The other half is hidden behind a map.

I have tried floating the element that contains the addthis snippet to the left but there is an issue with my selectors as the the social media buttons at the top of the page (within the header) are then affected. I only want to apply styling to the "in page" like buttons, if you will.

I've attached a screen: [image: Facebook comment box issue]

Other things that I have tried:
Setting overflow of containing element to visible

I'm suspicious that the issue may be due to my lack of ability to select the correct element. This element is a cut n paste code snippet from a 3rd party (addthis).

If anyone can offer some pointers I'd be super grateful. Site is here, if you click on any of the "reports": http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr

I'm seeking advice on best approach (What element to try to alter) and do what with.

---

I've found a temp solution for now. I floated the containing element to the left and changed the overflow to visible. This alters the site elements to fit the Like button behavior, rather than the other way around. If I knew how to display the like button pop out above all other elements (I tried z-index) I would have done that or, better, had the pop out dialogue pop out to the left rather than to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding style="overflow:visible;" to the parent element of class="addthis_toolbox" solved my problem.